# Multisymplectic connections and topological invariants

Tags: gn.general-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, connections, symplectic-topology

I was wondering if there exists any notion of multisymplectic connection that naturally generalizes symplectic (Fedosov) connections in symplectic geometry.

From symplectic connections, it is well known how to build the corresponding curvature tensor and define the proper topological classes.
I was wondering if there exists a similar construction in multisymplectic geometry.